# How to copy production Project Server 2010 to testing environment?

Tags: project-server

I have an Project Server 2010 environment on production with some tweak. I mean I have custom fields, some workflows, webparts, reports, lookup fields. I want to copy all that to my testing environment. The servers are physicals.

What can I do?

Comment: Is your project server virtualized ?

Comment: Nope, is physical.